# How to know if a thread is in deadlock state or not?

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded-linux, deadlock

I have created two threads written in C code and it is running on Linux OS. Both of the threads are doing some job and it's running forever while its parent process is alive.

The process which created those threads is sending a watchdog notification to `systemd` at some interval. However, before sending a watchdog notification, it wants to check whether all the threads are in a non-deadlock state or not.

What system call can be used, or what mechanism can be used, in code to know that thread is not in deadlock state so that the process can check whether its created threads are in deadlock state or not, and only send the watchdog notification to `systemd` if all the thread are in a non-deadlock state.

Comment: When a thread is about to acquire a system resource, store a time stamp for the parent thread. When a thread gets the system resource, invalidate the time stamp. If the parent thread sees a time stamp that is out-of-date by more than some limit, it can declare that the system is deadlocked.

Comment: What do you mean by store a time stamp for the parent thread? How parent thread will know that child thread is about to acquire a system resource. Could you please share a sample example to achieve my goal

Comment: The OS cannot determine this in any effective way.  You need to build in such checking into your app design, should you desire it, can design it, and if you can implement it without introducing more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do it is to have each thread that you need to track update its own shared variable periodically. The monitoring consists of checking to see that the shared variable changes value often enough.

Consider an analogy. You aren't home very often, but you want to make sure that your two children haven't disappeared. So you have a jar for each child. You tell them to add a penny to the jar every time they come home. Now, each time you come home, you count the pennies in each jar. If any child's jar has had the same number of pennies for too long, you know you have a problem.

So, for example, you can modify each thread doing work from:

1. Do some work.
2. Go to 1.

To:

1. Do some work.
2. Increment my progress variable.
3. Go to step 1.

Then the monitoring thread just has to track the last time it saw a different value for the state variable and the current value. It can then detect a deadlocked thread as follows:

1. Loop over each thread we're monitoring.
2. Is its state variable different than it was last time? If not, go to step 5.
3. Store the value we see for its state variable and store the current time.
4. Continue the loop we started in step 1.
5. Is the time we stored for this thread's last update too far in the past? If so, report a deadlock.
6. Continue the loop we started in step 1.

Comment: I think 2nd case will work for some of the cases. Lets assume , thread called select in loop and thread is in blocking state. It loop will continue only if select get signal and then only 'state variable' is updated. Main thread which is monitoring  this thread at some interval will get old state variable value  since select is not triggered at that interval of time in which main thread is checking state variable, Since Main thread checked that it holds old value , it report a deadlock however thread is not in deadlock state.

Comment: @VikashRanjan You have to set an appropriate timeout in `select`. Otherwise, add a pipe end to the `select` set and have the monitoring thread use it to trigger. Yes, this has to be built into the design -- it's no something you sprinkle on top randomly.

Comment: @VikashRanjan Read my answer. That's precisely what I explain. Design the thread to increment a state variable every so often and if it's not changing, it's deadlocked.

Comment: I think above monitoring check will be work for specific design.                     Is it any way to get the thread status whether it is in deadlock or not? Is it any way  to know thread  state is in D (Uninterruptible sleep)?

Comment: @VikashRanjan I don't understand what you're asking. My answer explains a way to do that. If the thread is stuck in uninterruptible sleep, it won't be able to change the shared variable, which the monitoring thread could detect.

Comment: 1.Is it any way  to know what is the state( TASK_RUNNING, TASK_UNINTERUPTIBLE or TASK_INTERUPTIBLE) of that thread ?                                                                                           
 2. If a thread is in deadlock state does it mean thread state will be always in D (Uninterruptible sleep)?                                                                                                             
If  We know answer of 1st and if 2nd case is true then without using any shared variable we can achieve  whether thread is in deadlock state or not and it will work forever

Comment: @VikashRanjan You seem to be asking how to detect that software has crashed. That question is way too broad for stack overflow. If you want software that works forever, then you need to design it correctly, implement it carefully, and debug it thoroughly.

Comment: @VikashRanjan No, you really don't. If it's in uninterruptible sleep, it could just be waiting for disk I/O that will complete in a split second. My answer explains how to detect that a thread has deadlocked.

Comment: Thanks David your suggestion. I am able to check  deadlock state. Thanks for your valuable input.